# Extended glob expression on makefile

Tags: makefile, zsh, gnu-make, glob

Consider the file structure created by the commands below in zsh.

```
mkdir fff fff/a fff/b
touch fff/{a,a/a,b/a,}.{x,y,z}
```

I want to glob all files in all subdirectories of 'fff' that do not have the 'z' extension. So,

```
ls fff/**/^*.z(.)
```

does the trick in an interactive shell, assuming `extended_glob` option is set. However, when I use the above cl in a makefile like this

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh
list_not_z :
    ls fff/**/^*.z(.)
```

it does not mach anything and reports the error:

> ls fff/**/^*.z(.)
>
> zsh:1: no matches found: fff/**/^*.z(.)

On the other hand, globbing all files that have the 'z' extension with `ls fff/**/*.z(.)` works interactively as well as in the makefile. So, I suspect it has something to do with the fact that `^` belongs to zsh's exteneded glob syntax. The respective option `extended_glob` is set in my .zshrc.

Why does the glob work as expected in an interactive shell but does not when executed by GNU make as part of a recipe of a makefile?

Comment: "assuming extended_glob option is set". `make` is using a non-interactive shell, and `.zshrc` file isn't being sourced here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make` isn't sourcing your `.zshrc` file for the non-interactive shell it uses to execute the recipe, so `extended_glob` isn't set.

The simplest thing to do would be to just run `zsh` explicitly, passing the `extended_glob` option as a command line argument.q

```
list_not_z:
        zsh -o extended_glob -c 'ls fff/**/^*.z(.)'
```